# How to install lessphp to be used in the assetic framework?

Tags: php, less, assetic, lessphp

I cannot find a way to add the **lessphp** files to my project so that **assetic** finds them. I do not wish to add extra `require` sentences to the assetic files or modify them in any way so future updates are easily made.

I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'lessc' not found in ....../kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter/LessphpFilter.php on line 87
```

The code on that line is the `lessc` intantiation:

```
  $lc = new \lessc();
```

Note: I cannot use Composer to install it since Composer brings some issues to my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assetic will not import `lessc.inc.php` for you. You have to do it manually.

I assume you are using Assetic standalone in your application, you should be doing something like this:

```
<?php

use Assetic\Asset\AssetCollection;
use Assetic\Asset\FileAsset;
use Assetic\Filter\LessphpFilter;

require "path/to/lessc.inc.php"; // You should include it yourself

$css = new AssetCollection(array(
    new FileAsset('/path/to/src/styles.less', array(new LessphpFilter())),
));
echo $css->dump();
```

But for that causalities that you are using Symfony2, you should configure lessphp filter in your `app/config/config.yml` like this:

```
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        []
    filters:
       cssrewrite: ~
       lessphp:
           file: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/leafo/lessphp/lessc.inc.php"
           apply_to: "\.less$"
```

Let me know.

Comment: I thought Assetic distribution included aaaall the needed libraries, at least I couldnt find anything about it in the documentation.